# Can this PHP code of getting a PDF from S3, using Ghostscript to convert it to a PNG and displaying it be better written?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ghostscript

I am currently using the following code to pull a PDF from S3, using Ghostscript to convert the pages to PNG images, then display them in the browser. It works fine, but is it possible to write it better?

1. Is it possible to not have to write and then delete the files and do all the processing in memory?
2. Is it possible to speed up the processing of the images, while still maintaining a crisp image?

Here's the code:

```
<?php

session_start();

$fileName = 'file-name.pdf';

require '/path/to/aws.phar';

$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'region'  => 'us-west-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => 'xxx',
        'secret'  => 'yyy',
    )
]);

try {
    $result = $s3->getObject([
        'Bucket' => 'bucket-name',
        'Key'    => $fileName,
        ]
    );
        
    file_put_contents('/file/path/to/test.pdf', $result['Body']->getContents());
    
    $command = 'gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r253 -dDownScaleFactor=2 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -sOutputFile=/file/path/to/' . session_id() . '_test%d.png -q /file/path/to/test.pdf';

    exec($command . ' 2>&1', $output, $exitCode);

    $files = scandir('/Users/markwheeler/Sites/rh/gs-test');

    echo '<div style="margin: 0 auto; max-width: 1070px;">';

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (preg_match('/^' . session_id() . '_test(\d+)\.png$/i', $file, $matches)) {
            $index = $matches[1];
    
            $fh = fopen('/file/path/to/' . $file, 'r');
            $theData = fread($fh, filesize('/file/path/to/' . $file));
            fclose($fh);
        
            echo '<div><img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($theData) . '"></div>';
    
            unlink('/file/path/to/' . $file);
        }
    }

    unlink('/file/path/to/test.pdf');
    
    echo '</div>';
} catch (Aws\Exception\AwsException $e) {
    echo "File download error: " . $e->getMessage();
} catch (Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
    echo "error: " . $e->getMessage();
} catch(Aws\Exception\CredentialsException $e) {
    echo 'error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

// EOF
```

Thanks for all your input.

Comment: You can't avoid writing the PDF file because PDF files require random access to process them. You can send the file to Ghostscript's stdin, but then it will just write the data to a temporary file, so you won't save anything. You can send the output to stdout, or a pipe or anywhere else you want it, if that helps you. You are using both DownScaleFactor **and** AlphaBits, don't use both because they do the same thing, use one or the other. AlphaBits is faster, DownScaleFactor more reliable. If you are using AlphaBits instead of DownScaleFactor you can reduce the resolution which is faster.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the tips. I’ll do the suggested changes for Ghostscript and see if helps the speed. As to sending the output of Ghostscript to stdout, the trouble I found with that is not figuring out how to separate each page of the pdf and subsequently covert to base64. I’m unsure of how to do that.

Comment: You can't have Ghostscript produce a file per page when sending to stdout, because how would you know when each file was complete ? So basically if you want a page per file output, then you need to use files.

Comment: I was afraid of that. So as the code stands now, my best bet is to mess with the DownScaleFactor and AlphaBits. Hopefully that will cut down some of the processing time - or look for something other than Ghostscript.

Comment: Both DownscaleFactor and AlphaBits involve anti-aliasing, so the result is a **less** 'crisp' image (anti-aliasing involves blurring the edges). So you could turn off both and get sharper images more quickly. Or just use AlphaBits, DownscaleFactor involves doubling the resolution and scaling down by 2, so 4 times the data is produced, and then reduced. Or, as you say, try something else, there are other PDF consumers.